# "Incorrect number of dimensions" message when retrieving data from a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with subset groups, gender and other things.
I am trying to retrieve data of males, then I use the command

```
data[data$gender == "male",]
```

But it keeps to say incorrect number of dimensions, how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems to me that you used the correct code. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Guess you are having a data frame. Try library(dplyr); df %>% filter(gender == "male")

Comment: If this is data frame, code presented in question will work anyway. I guess the class of data is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

An illustration using dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(gender = rep(c("male", "female"), each=5),
                 loveToBuy = c("car", "car", "computer", "rolex", "boat",
                               rep("handbag", 5)))
df2 = df %>% filter(gender == "male")
df2
#   gender loveToBuy
# 1   male       car
# 2   male       car
# 3   male  computer
# 4   male     rolex
# 5   male      boat
```

Comment: Works fine, same as `df[df$gender=='male',]`.